# Grails spring security plugin AJAX authentication

Tags: ajax, grails, curl, spring-security

I have been searching high and low for the answer to this. I would like to be able to send JSON data at a Grails application with the spring security core plugin that will validate authentication. I can't seem to get this to work.

I'm trying to test this using cURL with the following command:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data @ajax_login.json http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check?ajax=true
```

My ajax_login.json looks like this:

```
{
    "j_username":"user@email.com",
    "j_password":"password"
}
```

My response looks like this:

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /j_spring_security_check?ajax=true HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 63
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=974763464D383CD90962E8933DBB8335; Path=/
< Set-Cookie: grails_remember_me=""; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/
< Location: http://localhost:8080/login/authfail;jsessionid=974763464D383CD90962E8933DBB8335?ajax=true
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 12 Dec 2012 22:53:27 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

I was hoping to see something like this as per the ajaxSuccess action of LoginController:

```
{
    "success":true,
    "username":"user@email.com"
}
```

or at least the failure JSON per the ajaxfail action of LoginController:

```
{
    "error":"#yourdoingitwrong"
}
```

FYI, my config.groovy has this:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
  '/css/**':    ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
  '/common.css':  ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
  '/favicon.ico': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
  '/images/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
  '/js/**':   ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
  '/login/**':  ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
  '/logout/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
  '/register/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
  '/error/**':  ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
  '/**':      ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED']
]
```

I have subclassed GormUserDetailsService and overridden loadUserByUsername to do my own lookup but the username that is passed in is blank...empty string. I know this because I am able to set a breakpoint in that method and when I send my cURL command, execution DOES end up there.

Anything other details I'm missing?

Comment: Http stats 302 means a redirect. What happens if you try to call the url that appears in the "location" after the login post? In your example is: http://localhost:8080/login/authfail;jsessionid=974763464D383CD90962E8933DBB8335?ajax=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding parameter -L to curl command should help

Following part in your server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily 
Location: http://localhost:8080/login/authfail;jsessionid=974763464D383CD90962E8933DBB8335?ajax=true
```

tells curl/browser that the requested page has moved to new location (*login/authfail*). This way server redirects client to new URL. **Web browser** would immediately issue request to the new location, but default behavior of **curl** is not to follow redirects automaticaly.

Parameter **-L/--location** instructs curl to follow redirects. See **man curl** for more details.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was missing! I can see that in the cURL help but I don't really get why that is what I needed. Can you explain what that added?

Answer (score 1):

I would still like to know how to issue a cURL command as requested but I was able to successfully communicate via jQuery.ajax:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#btnPush').on('click', function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    j_username: 'user@email.com',
                    j_password: 'password'
                },
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert('Success!!!');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Fail!');
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button id='btnPush'>Push Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This HTML file had to be included in my Grails applications web-app folder. I'm guessing that is so that it is not a cross-domain request.